# Android align action bar menu items to the left

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am created a menu item using java not xml on my actionbar which contains sub-menu as well. I am wondering is there any way i could move to the extreme left

[image]

JAVA CODE TO CREATE MENU ITEM AND SUB MENU INSIDE IT

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Navigation Menu");
    subMenu.add("Library").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_book);
    subMenu.add("On Device").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_tablet);
    subMenu.add("My Shelf").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_laptop);
    MenuItem subMenu1Item = subMenu.getItem();
    subMenu1Item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_home);
    subMenu1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);      
    return true;
}
```